# Python split() fails when using delimiter

Tags: python, split

i'm trying to parse a feedback string from a device.  i'm just trying to run a simple `split()` but it throws this error: `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`.  this makes no sense to me.

```py
  workingResult = "SIMState: READY\nSIMMCC: 262\nSIMMNC: 01\nRegState: Registered, home network\nSigQuality: Good\nSigQualitydBm: -72\nAccessTec: 4G\nLastUpdate: 19.02.20_12:25:37"

  strip1 = workingResult.replace('\n', ',')
  strip2 = list(strip1.split(','))
  finalDict = {}
  for item in strip2:
    print(f'{type(item)}, {item}')
    key, value = item.split(': ')  #<-- problem child
    print(key,value)
    finalDict[key] = value
```

if it try the 'problem child' line with a single assignment, `key = item.split(': ')` i get the single line as one would expect.  this should be a simple dump into two vars, but i don't get the error.  i also tried trimming the delimiter to just `':'` with no space, but got the same error.

what am i missing here?

Comment: The loop is hitting `' home network'` and breaking because it doesn't follow the `'key: value'` format. Here's what you get if you `print(split2)`: `['SIMState: READY', 'SIMMCC: 262', 'SIMMNC: 01', 'RegState: Registered', ' home network', 'SigQuality: Good', 'SigQualitydBm: -72', 'AccessTec: 4G', 'LastUpdate: 19.02.20_12:25:37']`

Comment: You have a comma in your input (`Registered,`). Why replace `\n` with `,`? Just split on newlines.

Comment: i added the comma just as part of troubleshooting and figured i'd just leave it in.  i trust nothing when things go sideways.  :P

Comment: @jRiggles: holy crap, i totally missed that.  i'd trimmed the actual output for posting here for security reasons and readability.  i never really thought the data would be this bad coming in.  thanks for the better eyes.  and as @ Woodford mentioned, that comma screwed things up when i broke it into commas instead of straight out.  *sigh*  thanks again, gents.  much appreciated.

Comment: This could be done with just `final_dict = dict(item.split(': ') for item in working_result.splitlines())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if `'home network'` belongs to `'RegState'` or to `'SigQuality'`, but simply doing `workingResult.splitlines()` (or `workingResult.split('\n')`) yields this:

```
['SIMState: READY', 'SIMMCC: 262', 'SIMMNC: 01', 'RegState: Registered, home network', 'SigQuality: Good', 'SigQualitydBm: -72', 'AccessTec: 4G', 'LastUpdate: 19.02.20_12:25:37']
```

which seems to work as you might expect when converting to a `dict`

```
workingResult = "SIMState: READY\nSIMMCC: 262\nSIMMNC: 01\nRegState: Registered, home network\nSigQuality: Good\nSigQualitydBm: -72\nAccessTec: 4G\nLastUpdate: 19.02.20_12:25:37"

strip1 = workingResult.split('\n')

finalDict = {}
for item in strip1:
    k, v = item.split(': ')
    finalDict[k] = v
    
print(finalDict)
# >>> {'SIMState': 'READY', 'SIMMCC': '262', 'SIMMNC': '01', 'RegState': 'Registered, home network', 'SigQuality': 'Good', 'SigQualitydBm': '-72', 'AccessTec': '4G', 'LastUpdate': '19.02.20_12:25:37'}
```

For completeness' sake, here's the same thing with a dictionary comprehension instead of a `for` loop:

```
finalDict = {k: v for item in strip1 for k, v in [item.split(': ')]}
```

Comment: home network does, in fact, belong to RegState.  the guys who built the API i'm working with apparently didn't really think it through.  but it's what we get to work with.  stuff like this trips us up all the time with other calls.  :P  and the final line, basically @buran answer, is the solution i'll use, but this tidies up loose ends and has a more readable version for other possible implementations.  thanks again.